# Why big websites don't prefer localstorage over cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I'd like to ask why big players like facebook, google still uses cookies if localstorage is much better and secure for same.

Comment: May be because of `Legacy Browsers`.. [__Browser Support__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Google and Facebook use both, localstorage and cookies. Maybe they use cookies because it's easier to get them on the server. With localstorage you will need to add it to request and cookies are send automatically.

Comment: "if localstorage is much better and secure for same." [citation needed] */me looks at his noscript plugin and thinks wtf???*

Comment: @PeeHaa It's not duplicate of your mentioned link. Both are technically different.

Comment: Considering you don't understand the difference between the two making your question pretty much impossible toanswer I would say the dupe suits you just fine. Also *citation* is till *needed*.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing at all: you can use them in a similar way, but they serve different purposes.

Take a look at this thread: [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)